# How to create a multi dimensional array across the Class and TestClass in Java with user input

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm sort of stuck in limbo with this problem because there are no examples of it in my class's textbook, so I'm not really even sure how to start. Total beginner. I have a class and a test class for a program that's supposed to take user input and put it into a multidimensional array. The data is supposed to be collecting the values of utility bills over 6 months. So I have 3 bills for 6 months, so I figured in the base class I would write something like:

```java
public class UtilityBill {

    //declare arrays
    private double[][] month = new double[6][3]; //create array to store each of the 3 bills every month
    private String[] utility = new String[3];

    //contructor
    public UtilityBill(double[][] month, String[] utility) {
        this.month = month;
        this.utility = utility;
    }



    //sets and gets for both arrays objects
    public void setUtility(String[] utility) {
        this.utility = utility;
    }

    public String[] getUtility(String[] utility) {
        return utility;
    }

    public void setMonth(double[][] month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public double[][] getMonth(double[][] month) {
        return month;
    }

             

}
```

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UtilityBillTest {
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[][] utilityArray = 
        UtilityBill utility3 = new UtilityBill


    }

}
```

This is all I have so far. But in the test class I have no idea what to do, and the textbook that the professor assigned us isn't helping much because all the examples are just of isolated classes with no test class or whatever. How do I create this from user input across both the base class and the test class? Sorry if the questions very general, I'm still 100% beginner to any sort of programming.

Comment: In order for something to test you need to have something more in your class. Can you add the code of your whole class? That makes it easier to give you some guidance

Comment: Yeah! Hold on a sec

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the array by user input, do like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        double[][] month = new double[6][3];

        System.out.println("please input month bill");
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                month[i][j] = in.nextDouble();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("please input utility");
        String[] utility = new String[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            utility[i] = in.next();
        }
        UtilityBill utilityBill = new UtilityBill(month, utility);
    }
```

PS: getter method no need parameter

```
    public String[] getUtility() {
        return utility;
    }

    public double[][] getMonth() {
        return month;
    }
```